# Empty Map when using Executors

Tags: java

I'm trying to count for each minute the records with the same `type` as in the parameter in a `List`, in a given time range. Using the following Method:

```
public Map<String, Object> getCountPerMinuteForType(final String type,
                                 final long startTimestamp,
                                 final long endTimestamp) {
    final Map<String, Object> countsPerMinForType = new HashMap<>();
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            int counter = 0;
            List<Data> dataList = storage.retrieveData();
            for(Data data: dataList){
                if (data.getType().equals(type) &&
                    data.getUnixTimestamp() >= startTimestamp &&
                    data.getUnixTimestamp() <= endTimestamp){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            countsPerMinForType.put(type, counter);
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    return countsPerMinForType;
}
```

The problem is, this method returns an empty `Map`.

When I print the contents of the `Map` inside the `Executors`, I can see that it has data.

Comment: @Abra I have a stream of data which will take -if any- a long time. I want to return the count for each minute and not wait for the data to completely load.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _stream of data_. I can guess. Are you familiar with the [java concurrency utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/) that were first added in Java 5 and have been added to in subsequent Java releases? Or perhaps the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) is appropriate? Or perhaps [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because an another thread is performing put operation in the Map. The main thread starts execution of the thread and then returns back to the place where it was called. To solve this issue, you may need to create a listener interface which gets called whenever the second thread performs the task.

Here, below is the code sample which you can use and modify according to your needs.

```
class Test implements Listener {
    private Listener listener;

    public Test() {
        listener = this; //Set this class as your listener
    }

    //Make your function return nothing
    public void getCountPerMinuteForType(final String type, final long startTimestamp, 
    final long endTimestamp) {

    final Map<String, Object> countsPerMinForType = new HashMap<>();
    ScheduledExecutorService service = 
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        int counter = 0;
        List<Data> dataList = storage.retrieveData();
        for (Data data : dataList) {
            if (data.getType().equals(type) &&
                    data.getUnixTimestamp() >= startTimestamp &&
                    data.getUnixTimestamp() <= endTimestamp) {
                counter++;

            }
        }
        listener.onNewData(type, counter);
        countsPerMinForType.put(type, counter);
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        //return countsPerMinForType;
        //If service is terminated call the listener and perform your operation there
        if (service.isTerminated()) {
            listener.dataFilled(countsPerMinForType);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewData(String str, Object obj) {
        //Perform your task here
    }
    @Override
    public void dataFilled(Map<String, Object> data) {
        //Perform your task here
    }
}

interface Listener {
    void dataFilled(Map<String, Object> data);
    void onNewData(Map<String, Object> data);
}
```

Comment: I think this would wait for the data to load, the problem is: i have a stream of data which will take -if any- a long time.So I want to return the count for each minute and not wait for the data to "completely" load.

Comment: If you have stream of data then call the listener when you put data inside the map. It will cause interrupts whenever data is received.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you're expecting the thread you're spinning off has completed the work and the results populated in the `countsPerMinForType` are returned. This is not what is happening...

What is happening is:

1. you call the method from the main/current thread of execution
2. the `Map` is created
3. a new thread is spun off to do some work
4. almost immediately, the method returns and the map is still empty.
   ...
5. after the method has completed, the work being performed by the spun off thread is then carried out... and subsequently the calling method never sees the result.

You can confirm this is the case with a *test* that returns a `timestamp` for when the `getCountPerMinuteForType` starts and ends, and another `timestamp` for when the `Thread` starts and ends. The start times will be in order, the end times will not be in order.

Also, you may want to consider using a `ConcurrentHashMap` for a multi-threaded application.